# Powershell keep only n latest items in folder (builds rotation)

Tags: powershell, scripting, directory

For purpose of builds rotation I want to keep only 10 latest items in folder. Builds are located in subfolders named by id (increasing order) of build.

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----          21.8.15   7:39 PM                121
d-----          21.8.15  10:39 PM                122
d-----          21.8.15  10:39 PM                123
d-----          21.8.15  10:39 PM                124
d-----          21.8.15  10:39 PM                125
```

I want to know if is there more elegant way than one I use.

```
$exclude = dir | Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object Name -f 10
Get-Item * | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $exclude.Name -notcontains $_.Name} | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object -Skip $n` to skip `$n` folders and then remove the rest:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |Select-Object -Skip 2 | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Comment: Woow, thanks. This is nice and simple. Only please add -Descending. I forgot in my example. Thanks

Comment: @JaroslavKubacek Of course. I would probably also go for sorting on `LastWriteTime` instead. With the `Name` prop, if folder names where ie. `98,99,100`, it would fail (100 comes before 98, alphabetically)